# Topology for Rigging and Animation

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, topology

If my mesh is quad-based and retopologized does the poly count (high number) matter for successful deformation? I'm wondering if I have a high poly mesh, does that make rigging and animation easier or harder? And is best practice to use shrink wrap/displacement maps? I'm new to it so not sure. Just trying to avoid a bunch of trouble. Thanks!

Comment: avoid high-poly mesh if you want to animate, instead give your object a Subdivision Surface so that it keeps your object smooth. Add edge loops around the joints if you see that it helps to have a nice bend. Your question about shrinkwrap and displacement is a bit too vague though...

Comment: @moonboots thanks! Sorry for being vague. I'm wondering: when you retoplogize a mesh for the purpose of animation, can you make it low poly, then just use a displacement map so that all the high poly detail is maintained and useable? Or what's the best way to accomplish that? thanks again!

Comment: To keep all the details of the high-poly, bake your high-poly and use the normal map you get, with a Normal Map node, look inot tutorials about high-poly low-poly and bake normals. Displacement use height map, not normal map, which is another way to ad fake 3D, so I don't think it will be useful here...

Comment: @moonboots thanks so much! Can you help me understand a little more: If I have just sculpted a highly detailed face and want to animate it, it's not necessary to go in and retoplogize all the detail, correct? I can project all the detail onto the low poly retop using subsurf/multires + shrink wrap? Is this inferior to going the normal-wrap route?

Comment: keep the Subsurf on both the high and low-poly, but you don't need any Shrinkwrap. Don't retopologize, keep the face low-poly and make a test to see what it gives once you plug the normal map